# scipy solve_ivp with negative first_step

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I want to solve a system of ODEs with scipy's solve_ivp and I need a negative first_step in order to evolve the solution, but

```
Nsol = solve_ivp(derivs, (N , Nend), ydoub, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, first_step=-1e-8)
```

returns

```
ValueError: `first_step` must be positive.
```

Any ideas how to resolve this or find a way around it?

EDIT: here is the code which yields this:

```
import numpy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

w = numpy.array ( [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   3.17214587e-01,
        -3.41988549e-01,  -1.50137165e-05,  -2.48117074e-02,
         1.17624224e-03,  -1.27149037e-04] )

def derivs2 (t, w):
    dydN = numpy.zeros(2 , dtype=float , order='C')

    dydN[0] = 0.0

    dydN[1] = y[1] * y[2]
    dydN[2] = y[2] * ( y[3] + 2.0 * y[2] )
    dydN[3] = 2.0 * y[4] - 5.0 * y[2] * y[3] - 12.0 * y[2] * y[2]

    for i in range (4 , NEQS-1):
        dydN[i] = ( 0.5 * (i-3) * y[3] + (i-4) * y[2] ) * y[i] + y[i+1]

    dydN[NEQS-1] = ( 0.5 * (NEQS-4) * y[3] + (NEQS-5) * y[2] ) * y[NEQS-1]

    return dydN

Nsol = solve_ivp(derivs, (1000.0 , 0.0), w, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False , first_step=-1e-6)
```

Comment: Could you provide all the code necessary to reproduce this behavior, please!?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question to include the code.

Comment: Please also add all your imports so that one can easily copy&paste, thanks!

Comment: Okay, done that.

Comment: If you make `first_step` positive or leave it out, what exactly is then wrong in the result?

Comment: Your `derivs2` function can not work. Your state argument is `w`, but you use `y` for the computations inside. You initialize `dydN` with dimension 2, but immediately access elements 2 and 3 and then fill to some equally undefined size NEQS-1 (you are aware that range(n) returns values 0,...,n-1?). // As you care about the initialization of the step size controller in `first_step`, you should also explicitly set the values of the control parameters `atol, rtol`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many problems (`derivs` vs. `derivs2` and `w` vs `y`, etc.) and will not run.

`first_step` is actually the magnitude of the first step, this is not described clearly, or at all, in the documentation.  Change `first_step=1e-6` and this should work.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp 

def fun(t, y): 
    return y 

try: 
    sol = solve_ivp(fun, (1000, 0), [1], first_step=-1e-6) 
except ValueError: 
    print(f"fails backwards") 

sol = solve_ivp(fun, (1000, 0), [0], first_step=1e-6) 
print(sol.t) 
print("First step = {}".format(sol.t[1]-sol.t[0]))
```

result:

```
fails backwards
[1000.          999.999999    999.999989    999.999889    999.998889
  999.988889    999.888889    998.888889    988.88888903  888.88888928
    0.        ]
First step = -9.999999974752427e-07
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. There are other "holes" in the documentation. e.g., do you know what means "sorted" for the t_eval (time points to compute) when the t_span goes backward? should it be sorted in the same sense as the values in t_span or in increasing order?